# store multiple checkboxes of the foreach loop to the mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

The form that i have made

```
<input id="user_name" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo (($row['name'] == $row['name'])? $row['name'] : '') ?>" disabled="disabled" />
<input id="user_email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo (($row['email'] == $row['email'])? $row['email'] : '') ?>" disabled="disabled" />

<?php foreach ($lists as $list => $slug ) { ?>
    <li colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" id="list" name="rights[]" <?php if($slug == 1 ){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> /> <?php echo $list; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

here the checkboxes conditions:
 all checkboxs "rights[]" are 5 and 
 each checkbox value is 0/1, 0 if unchecked, 1 if checked (disable/enable)

i have created the table to store it as following

```
 <?php
    $rights             = ($_POST['rights']) ? $_POST['rights'] : 0;
//  $some_rights            = implode(',',$rights);

$conn->db_Exec("INSERT INTO %smoderator (id, name, email) VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s')", DB_PREFIX, $log_id, $name, $email);

foreach ($rights as $right) {
$conn->db_Exec("UPDATE %smoderator SET able_toedit = '$right', able_todel = '$right', able_toblock = '$right', able_tomove = '$right', able_tomark = '$right' WHERE id = '$log_id' LIMIT 1", DB_PREFIX);
}
?>
```

I found 2 problems here
1. The data sent through 2 step, INSERT 1st and then UPDATE, i have not succeeded making it in INSERT only, i looking for more efficient process and secure
2. if i tick 1,2 or more that are all stored become 0 in the table, how to cope it so that will sent according to the amount of checked?, need advice and help, thanks

Comment: First of all, you should only do one update (if I understand correctly). In the foreach loop increment a variable once for each checked box, then after the foreach loop, update the record with that count.

Comment: Where does `db_Exec` come from? If you're using placeholder values, do try and use them consistently. Values like `$right` should not be directly in your query, that's likely a [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: thank you Sloan Thrasher for your advices, but i have tried several ways, but i got stuck, e.g.  for ($j=0; $j > count ($rights); $j++; perhaps you have example scripts to do that may i see

Comment: Hi tadman, db_ Exec is come from function db_Exec() that execute sql statement in the database, yes, i wll try to using placeholder and hope this can help me, thank you